# Change PHP page if Conditions are met

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code as below I need it to change the PHP page to another page if the conditions are met, if it is not met it needs to send it back to the other page

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
        header("test.php");
    }
} else {
    echo"Wrong";
}
```

I have tested the above so the string and queries work now when I use the header function to change page nothing happens

I used header function to change the page when I echo a description where the header is I can see the IF function based on the Query

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, or a MySQL problem?

Comment: Please try to format your code appropriately when posting a question, so it's easier to read for the people answering! ;)

You might want to try adding `location` to your header string like such:

`header("location: test.php")`. Also make sure that the number of rows returned *is* actually at least 1.

Comment: Its a simple TYPO - a header needs the word `Location:` in front of the page name like this `header("Location: test.php");`

Comment: Thanks the Location was the issue I omitted it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this code

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
        header("location: test.php");//add location:
    }
}else{
    echo"Wrong";
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What did you change, and why?

Comment: We dont normally answer TYPO's, We make a comment to help and then close the question as TYPO's are never any real use to others which is the prime purpose of SO